# Building JSON in MySQL trigger AFTER UPDATE

Tags: mysql, json

It would be nice to get some help for implementing a trigger in MySQL 5.6 to log updated information.

First of all, this is my data table and my log table:

```
CREATE TABLE t1
(id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
 data1 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
 data2 DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE t1_log
(action VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
 timestamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
 id INTEGER NOT NULL,
 data1 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
 data2 DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL,
 data1_old VARCHAR(255),
 data2_old DECIMAL(5,2)
);
```

And this is my trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER after_update_t1 AFTER UPDATE ON t1
 FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
   INSERT INTO t1_log (action,timestamp,id,data1,data2,data1_old,data2_old)
   VALUES ('update',NOW(),NEW.id,NEW.data1,NEW.data2,OLD.data1,OLD.data2);
 END;
```

That works without any problems. But this solution has the disadvantage that I need a log table for every data table.  
So I thougt about a possibility to have only one log table with a BLOB field, combine the updated fields to an JSON string and store it in this BLOB. But how to define a trigger for that?

In pseudocode it looks like this:

```
BEGIN
  SET jsonString = "{"
  FOR EACH field in NEW
     jsonString += field.name + ":" + field.value + ","
  END FOR
  FOR EACH field in OLD
     jsonString += field.name + ":" + field.value + ","
  END FOR
  jsonString = TRIM(jsonString, ",") + "}"
  INSERT INTO log (action,timestamp,jsondata)
  VALUES ('update',NOW(),jsonString)
END
```

Answer (score 5):

If it were me and I had this requirement, I'd just use one of the existing audit log plugins. For example: https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/LATEST/management/audit_log_plugin.html

If you can't use the audit log plugin, or you just want to log your own JSON, at least avoid building a JSON value by string concatenation. That's too error-prone.

Instead, use the function [JSON_OBJECT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-creation-functions.html#function_json-object). This is available in MySQL 5.7 and later. If you're using an earlier version of MySQL and you want to work with JSON data, you should upgrade.

```
INSERT INTO log SET action = 'update', timestamp = NOW(),
  jsondata = JSON_OBJECT(
    'id', NEW.id,
    'data1', NEW.data1,
    'data2', NEW.data2
  );
```

I would also not recommend trying to make a single general-purpose trigger that can be used for any table. You need to define the trigger for each table you want to log anyway, so you should customize the trigger with the columns for the respective table.

You might be tempted to use INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS to gather a list of the columns of the table, but keep in mind that will do the work of querying INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS every time you do an INSERT or UPDATE against your base table. That's a lot of querying, and it will cause performance problems.